# Tensorflow: When re-running a training session, get_variable runs the initializer and recreate variables, instead of retrieving the existing variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

Since I am using get_variable to create and retrieve the variables, I would imagine that the 2nd time the training session is run, it would retrieve the variables and start where the last training session had left off, but this does not seem to be the case.

My code below

Code for the graph definition:

```
graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default(): 

  valid_examples = np.array(random.sample(range(1, valid_window), valid_size)) 

  train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, cbow_window*2 ])
  train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
  valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)
  valid_datasetSM = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)

  embeddings = tf.get_variable( 'embeddings', 
    initializer= tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))

  softmax_weights = tf.get_variable( 'softmax_weights',
    initializer= tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                         stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))

  softmax_biases = tf.get_variable('softmax_biases', 
    initializer= tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]),  trainable=False )
  embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset) 
  embed_reshaped = tf.reshape( embed, [batch_size*cbow_window*2, embedding_size] )


  segments= np.arange(batch_size).repeat(cbow_window*2)

  averaged_embeds = tf.segment_mean(embed_reshaped, segments, name=None)

  loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds,
                               labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))

  optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)

  norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keepdims=True))
  normSM = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(softmax_weights), 1, keepdims=True))

  normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
  normalized_embeddingsSM = softmax_weights / normSM

  valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
    normalized_embeddings, valid_dataset)
  valid_embeddingsSM = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
    normalized_embeddingsSM, valid_datasetSM)

  similarity = tf.matmul(valid_embeddings, tf.transpose(normalized_embeddings))
  similaritySM = tf.matmul(valid_embeddingsSM, tf.transpose(normalized_embeddingsSM))
```

Code for Tensorflow session to train variables in the graph ( the embeddings and softmax weights)

```
num_steps = 1000001

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  print('Initialized')
  average_loss = 0
  saveIteration = 1
  for step in range(num_steps):

    batch_data, batch_labels = generate_batch(
      batch_size, cbow_window)
    feed_dict = {train_dataset : batch_data, train_labels : batch_labels}
    _, l = session.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict) 

    average_loss += l
    if step % 2000 == 0:
      if step > 0:
        average_loss = average_loss / 2000
      print('Average loss at step %d: %f' % (step, average_loss))
      average_loss = 0
```

After this session is done running, I run only the code section above (I do NOT run the graph definition section or any other code section again) and the loss is around where it is at the beginning of the last training session, so it looks like get_variable is initializing`embeddings` and `softmax_weights` again, instead of retrieving the already created variables by their names in tensorflow ( `embeddings` and `softmax_weights` respectively).

I set the graph to default in the graph definition, so when I run the session it should be the same graph, and so it should still have the `embeddings` and `softmax_weights` variables for  get_variable to find and retrieve from Tensorflow's stored variables.

So why it is using the initializers again ( `initializer= tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0)` and `initializer= tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                             stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size))` ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time when you run a `tf.Session` all your variables get initialized:

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run() # <<--
```

But you can save and restore all trained values to proceed training.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  # ..do anything
  saver.save('path/to/model.ckpt')
```

Restore and proceed training:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  # restore variables from disk instead of initialization
  saver.restore(sess, "/path/to/model.ckpt")
  # ..do anything
  saver.save(sess, "path/to/model.ckpt")
```

Annotation:

The `tf.get_variable()` function is just used to build a `tf.Graph`. The graph and its variables itself does not store values. Only when the graph is executed with a session, the variables get fed with values.

Just a session will allocate memory to store the current values of variables.

The function `tf.get_variable()` is therefore not intended to obtain the values stored in a variable.

EDIT:

[TensorFlow documentation: Save and Restore](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/programmers_guide/saved_model#models)